# Architechture of Managed Navigation using Reuse Terms

Tags: 2013, term-store, managed-navigation, reuse-term

I'm currently designing a Managed Navigation using Term Store Term Sets both hierarchically and process based. An example would be Continent > Country > Region > Municipality as the hierarchy and Regions Only and Municipalities Only as different Process based Term Sets. I reuse the terms from the hierarchy to the processes witch eventually lead to the same SPWebs from different navigation views. Is this the right way to do it, or is there another, more appropriate way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the "reuse terms" feature on a site I've done.  I think that is the better way if you want the links to remain the same.  The other option seems to be Pinning, which keeps the structure but apparently does not keep any of the links.

Comment: Nice to hear! This is exactly what I do on each term through PowerShell `$term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl", $newUrl)`

Comment: so does this not answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does! Bounty awarded :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from this steps

1. Click on Site Settings (now on the top right)
2. Next, click on Navigation under “Look and Feel” usually on the top right
3. You will find yourself in the Global and Current Navigation settings menu. The Global Navigation is the menu at the top and the Current Navigation is the one on the left.
   For each of these you can choose to use “Managed Navigation” or “Structural Navigation”
4. What we need to do next is create our Navigation items in the Term Store. Lower in the page you will find an option to Open the “Term Store Management Tool”.
5. In the Term Store Management Tool, use the left pane to navigate to the Term Set you want to use for the navigation.
6. Using the little drop down arrow on the Term Set, Create Terms to reflect your desired navigation.
7. for each Term (navigation links) we have just created, use the tabs at the top to manage “Navigation” and “Term-Driven Pages”.

   You can choose between two Navigation Node Types:

   Simple Link or Header Term-Driven Page with Friendly URLThe Simple Link or Header is the more traditional   hyperlink to an item or create a heading to group links.

   The Term-Driven is a little more powerful as it allows for friendly urls.
8. Next we will set the Friendly URL by moving to the next tab for the term, Term-Driven Pages. There you will find options to change the friendly url as well as setting the target page for the hyperlink. (Can even set SEO properties! – cool). Click on Save when you are done
9. Time to see the results, notice my url

Comment: Please, stop adding just links as answers. When the link breaks, the answer will be super unhelpful!

Comment: And honestly, I see nothing in that link answering Benny's question regarding how the different termsets should be built up whit reusage of terms, and what the best practice is!

Comment: sorry robert, i will take care about it in my further answer.

Comment: Hey Jatin, Welcome to SPSE! Can you please edit your answer to remove the link and add relevant content? Otherwise it will have to be put on hold or deleted.

Comment: @Jatin Ambaliya, you should take care of it already in this answer. The risk is it will be deleted quite soon otherwise

Comment: I know how to implement the solution, I even have scripts automating the process. What I'm asking in the question is **if the concept of resuing terms is the preferred one** of what I'm trying to accomplish: a matrix (faceted) navigation.